# Extract first word from a column and insert into new column

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a dataframe below and want to extract the first word and insert it into a new column

```
Dataframe1:

COL1
Nick K Jones
Dave G Barros
Matt H Smith
```

Convert it to this:

```
Dataframe2:
COL1              COL2
Nick K Jones      Nick
Dave G Barros     Dave
Matt H Smith      Matt
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a regex (`"([A-Za-z]+)"` or `"([[:alpha:]]+)"`or `"(\\w+)"`) to grab the first word

```
Dataframe1$COL2 <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", Dataframe1$COL1)
```

Comment: why use `gsub` when you need to replace just first occurrence. use `sub`

Comment: @Saksham you're right `sub` would be better here, thanks

Comment: What if the first word is a number: 495 or Q1? When I try this formula it just keeps "Q" and not Q1, and for 495, it takes all the numbers after it: "495 3Be" @nongkrong

Comment: @Nick try the option `"(\\w+)"`, or you can add into the brackets the options for matching numbers, ie. `[0-9A-Za-z]+` and `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I basically just want to grab the first word (whether that be characters or numbers before a space). So if I have P1 Media, in the past it would print out P. For 495 54, it would print out everything instead of just 495. @nongkrong

Comment: @Nick Specifically, did you try `sub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", Dataframe1$COL1)`

Comment: That worked thanks! and last question: is there a way to make all of them lowercase? @nongkrong

Comment: @Nick: you can set the argument `ignore.case = TRUE` to not worry about case sensitivity anymore. Or use `tolower()`

Comment: The above worked.  I'm looking for a solution that, in addition to the one above,  creates a new column with the remaining variables after the split.  e.g. in the above example, we have a new column,  COL3 that has values as `K Jones`, `G Barros`

Comment: A regex question: what does the double backslash do in ```"(\\w+)"```? Is the first backslash escaping the second? Or the second, escaping the ```w+```? Something else?

Comment: @DavidCrow the first escapes the second during R evaluation of the string so `'\w+'` is passed to regex

Comment: @Rorschach: thanks for the response--and the patience! I'm a regex newbie.

Answer (score 53):

We can use function `stringr::word`:

```
library(stringr)

Dataframe1$COL2 <- word(Dataframe2$COL1, 1)
```

Comment: This works well but is very slow for larger data. I'm working with half-a-milion rows and `str_extract(Dataframe2$COL1, '[A-Za-z]+')` (also from the `stringr` package) is at least ten times faster.

Comment: clearly the best answer for a problem that is meant to be simple

Comment: Late to the party but Colibri's answer is the best as it answers not only this problem but also first X words too.

Answer (score 14):

The function `strsplit` can be useful

```
Dataframe1$COL2 <- strsplit(Dataframe1$COL1, " ")[[1]][1]
```

Then you can change the last bracketed number to select other parts from the string too.